# How to place Buttons in the middle of Textviews

Tags: android, button, textview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to get two android buttons to appear inbetween two textviews. But the first textview seems to be showing while the other textview and buttons are not appearing. I want it to look like:

"Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah BUTTON blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah BUTTON"

What I am seeing is:

"Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah "

Here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView 
        android:text="Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:text="BUTTON"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView 
        android:text=" blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:text="BUTTON"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code and remember that controls having weight property set as 1 will be equally adjusted accroding to their width if width property set to Fill_parent

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:text="Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah "
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <Button
        android:text="BUTTON"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <TextView 
        android:text=" blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah "
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <Button
        android:text="BUTTON"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You better use layout weights or relative layout to achieve what you want.

Check this for more info on layouts.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

Comment: Hi Serdar, thanks for you fast response, can you please provide an example of how to use layout weights to achieve what I want?

Comment: Check this link it's the best example for you. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

Answer (score 0):

You can go easily with providing "Layout width" attribute as "dp" value.

One other thing about your code not for your question. You may have use "android:text" attributes with values in here in order to clearly express your question. But if not, this is a bad practice. Try to put your String values always in the "strings.xml" file where you can find under the "values" directory.